# Map property based on a column that is not a Foreign Key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to map the Country property using the CountryCode column, which is not the PK column in the Country table.

```
public class User
{

   [ForeignKey("Country")   
   public string CountryCode { get;set; }


   public virtual Country Country
}

public class Country 
{ 
   [Key]
   public int CountryId {get;set;}

   public string CountryCode {get;set;}

}
```

Currently the above doesn't work because CountryCode isn't a foreign key.  **How do I map this in EF 6 so that it loads the property based on the CountryCode** and not look for the FK in the Country table.

Comment: What about making your code the primary key instead of an integer ? You would have to set it yourself when you create a country, and make it unique in the Country table

Comment: I don't think you can really, short of having `CountryCode` as a separate field in the `User` table, or doing what @RédaMattar said.

Comment: And really, if you think about it, it's not supposed to work the way you're asking for anyway. How would it work if you were doing it in plain SQL without EF? The FK always goes on the ID field.

Comment: What happens when you fill in 2 CountryCodes the same in the Country Table? Why do you want to replicate the information in the first place?

Comment: @JamesB There is a unique contraint on the countrycode.

Comment: @RédaMattar I'm not the dba, and the design is not up to me.

Comment: Why don't you reference Country via CountryId?

Answer (score 0):

Like This:-

```
public class User
{
  // other properties.

  public virtual Country Country;

}

public class Country 
{ 
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string CountryCode {get;set;}
}
```

Entity Framework should be able to work out form here the relationship. It will create a Country_Id field in your DB. You could also create a Mapper class using the Fluent API.

a quick example :-

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{

  public UserMap()
  {
     HasOptional(x=>x.Country);
  }

}
```

Comment: But the User table has CountryCode not Country_Id.  That was the point of my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Dont Think you can via "Foreign key". EF will expect the key of the foreign table to be key. :-)

You could use validation trigger to check. You would need to code the check.
if Your Poco implements `: IValidatableObject` then EF will call

```
public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {}
```

when updating your object.
 You can code the association check there.

Given this looks like code first against a DB.
If you wish to retain the  `public virtual Country Country;`
You will need to load the Property Country yourself .
and Mark it as `[NotMapped]`

If this is an existing DB you are coding to , [EF power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)
have a reverse engineer code first from DB option.
This tool can provide some valuable insight.